# Toolbar in first VC not appearing after unwind segue from second VC

Tags: swift, uitoolbar, unwind-segue

I have a string of TableView controllers. The first VC has a toolbar that is set up in a storyboard.  This toolbar appears when the first VC appears.  I then do a show segue to the next VC based on what toolbar button is pressed.  When I do an unwind segue back to the first VC the toolbar is gone.  I have searched a lot for this particular issue and I feel I must be setting something up wrong in the storyboard. I would appreciate any help.  See the screenshot below for the first VC after the unwind segue
[image: main storyboard]

[image: first vc after unwind]

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is a little embarrassing, but it also seems like a bug in IB.  The reason that the toolbar disappeared is that I did not put a toolbar at the bottom of the tableview, just the toolbar **buttons**. But why in that case should the buttons appear the first time that the VC loads? Or shouldn't it be impossible to put a bar button item into a view that doesn't have a toolbar already added? Sure seems like a bug to me.